# Angular parent-child interaction

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm sorry to be asking this question as variations on it have been asked before, but I'm stuck, and haven't been able to find a solution for this situation, and am not finding the Angular Material docs very helpful.

I'm using an Angular Material button, and I'm trying to call it from my app component.

Here is my app component code:

```
import { Component, ViewChild, OnInit, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ButtonComponent } from './components/button/button.component';
import { MatTooltip} from '@angular/material'


    @Component({

  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'replace-services-project';

  @ViewChild(ButtonComponent) buttonComponent:ButtonComponent

  onClick(text:string){
      this.buttonComponent.onClick(text);
  }
 }
```

Here is my app component template

```
<div style="text-align:center">

    <div class="button-row">

        <button  mat-raised-button matTooltip="Info about the action"  color="primary" (click)="onClick('First Button')">
            First Button
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my button component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-button',
  templateUrl: './button.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./button.component.css']
})
export class ButtonComponent {


  onClick=(text:string)=>{
    console.log(text);
  }

  constructor() { }

  }
```

When I get to the line **this.buttonComponent.onClick(text);**, I get a runtime error in the console saying:  ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'onClick' of undefined.

Comment: Well, you don't have any <app-button> anywhere in your template. So how could @ViewChild(ButtonComponent) find the button component?

Comment: @kickinchicken why do you write method like this: onClick=(text:string)=>{...} instead onClick(text: string) {...} is there any benefit?

Comment: @JBNizet - the docs for the material component say that this is the way it works.

Comment: @josip:  I tried that initially, but wasn't able to get that method to work either.

Comment: No, they don't. If a component selector is app-button, it will be created if you have an <app-button> element in the template. That's fundamental Angular stuff. If you think the angular material claims otherwise, then point to a specific piece of documentation, so that we can explain it to you.

Answer (score 0):

Angular is seeing "button" as regular html button, not your custom component. Your selector is

```
selector: 'app-button',
```

Try to use

```
<app-button></app-button>
```

instead.

Comment: Thanks @ramden.  The material components don't work like that.  They basically extend normal components.  Sorry for the delay.

Comment: In case of material and button, material is just a directive/pipe that changes some properties of the button (more like a decorator), but they dont do anything to alter onClick. The problem as you described it is solved by using the component selector where you defined your onClick custom method. You can also try to put the custom method on AppComponent, there it would work, as the button is on in the AppComponent template, but you created a custom component and there is no way angular could know there to find the method of yours (in what component)